# How do I do a SHA1 File Checksum in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sha1, checksum

How do I use the `SHA1CryptoServiceProvider()` on a file to create a SHA1 Checksum of the file?

Answer (score 87):

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\file\location", FileMode.Open))
using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
{
    using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
    {
        byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(bs);
        StringBuilder formatted = new StringBuilder(2 * hash.Length);
        foreach (byte b in hash)
        {
            formatted.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", b);
        }
    }
}
```

`formatted` contains the string representation of the SHA-1 hash. Also, by using a `FileStream` instead of a byte buffer, `ComputeHash` computes the hash in chunks, so you don't have to load the entire file in one go, which is helpful for large files.

Comment: You should use a `StringBuilder` instead of generating 20 strings in the process of building the hash string.

Comment: `FileStream` is `IDisposable` and should also be used in a `using` block.

Comment: StringBuilder initial capacity should be twice the number of bytes in the hash

Comment: Edited to reflect @MarkHeath's comment and added a BufferedStream to improve performance.

Comment: I don't think you need to use BufferedStream. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2069317/64334

Comment: Tested with 100,000 iterations, BufferedStream makes no difference, so I'm going to remove it from the example. I also tested an alternate way of generating the string of the hash, using BitConverter, and it offers a moderate (6%) performance increase (and less LoC), so modifying that in the example as well.

Comment: Easier way to convert bytes to string: `Convert.ToBase64String(hash)`

Comment: @Roland - That is not an equivalent representation. The example is hex, not base 64. However, you could do `BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-","")`

Comment: This solution will be quite slow, especially on large files, because `ComputeHash` internally using very small 4k buffer. `FileStream` by default also have 4k buffer. So you need to increase `FileStream` buffer at least. Or, for best performance, completely replace `ComputeHash` with `TransformBlock`/`TransformFinalBlock` pair.

Answer (score 67):

With the ComputeHash method. See here:

[ComputeHash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.computehash.aspx)

Example snippet:

```
using(var cryptoProvider = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
{
    string hash = BitConverter
            .ToString(cryptoProvider.ComputeHash(buffer));

    //do something with hash
}
```

Where buffer is the contents of your file.

Comment: +1 for a great tip on using the `BitConverter` to generate a hex-string in one go.

Comment: SHA1CryptoServiceProvider should be wrapped in a `using` block

Comment: `BitConverter` separates bytes with a dash AA-F0-CC unlike @mgbowen's solution.  May or may not be what is desired.

Answer (score 6):

If you are already reading the file as a stream, then the following technique calculates the hash as you read it. The only caveat is that you need to consume the whole stream.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String sourceFileName = "C:\\test.txt";
            Byte[] shaHash;

            //Use Sha1Managed if you really want sha1
            using (var shaForStream = new SHA256Managed())
            using (Stream sourceFileStream = File.Open(sourceFileName, FileMode.Open))
            using (Stream sourceStream = new CryptoStream(sourceFileStream, shaForStream, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                //Do something with the sourceStream 
                //NOTE You need to read all the bytes, otherwise you'll get an exception ({"Hash must be finalized before the hash value is retrieved."}) 
                while(sourceStream.ReadByte() != -1);                
                shaHash = shaForStream.Hash;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(shaHash));
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 for `CryptoStream`. it could be useful in case you want to read a file from somewhere (eg : from an http request), write it to some place (eg: on disk) and at the same time compute the hash.

Comment: On a test on a large file, this code performed orders of magnitude worse than the `ComputeHash` solutions. Maybe it's the `ReadByte` one-at-a-time reading?

Comment: @MichaelKropat interesting. Good to know. 10 times, 100 times slower?

Comment: @MichaelKropat - just thought, if the overhead is because my example reads every byte, then this is moot if you are using the stream anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Also you can try:

```
FileStream fop = File.OpenRead(@"C:\test.bin");
string chksum = BitConverter.ToString(System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(fop));
```