# SHA1 File Hash in Classic ASP or ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, file, asp-classic, sha1

I have a website that allows users to upload files which are in turn stored in a Microsoft SQL Database.

The database contains hundreds of thousands of images and is becoming unmanagable. As such I've written a powershell script that extracts those images from the database to the filesystem and then generates a SHA1 hash of the file as such:

$SHA1 = Get-Checksum -Algorithm sha1 -File ($Dest + "$i.jpg")

Going forward I no longer want to store images in the database but rather use the file system however I still need to generate SHA1 hashes of each file.

I've been unable to find any documentation on generating SHA1 file hashes in classic asp or asp.net (c# or vb.net).

**Note I specifically need to know how to generate *FILE HASHES* - not hashes of strings.**

Has anyone else done this or know if or how it can be done? Any example code you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Brad

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do a SHA1 File Checksum in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993903/how-do-i-do-a-sha1-file-checksum-in-c)

Comment: http://www.componentworkshop.com/blog/2009/06/26/generating-sha1-and-md5-hashes-in-net-c-java-and-ruby

Comment: are you using sql server 2008? you could use filestream...

Comment: hey, just politely flagged this just because it's basically answered in another question

Answer (score 1):

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\file\location", FileMode.Open))
using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
{
    using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
    {
        byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(bs);
        StringBuilder formatted = new StringBuilder(2 * hash.Length);
        foreach (byte b in hash)
        {
            formatted.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", b);
        }
    }
}
```

`formatted` contains the string representation of the SHA-1 hash. Also, by using a `FileStream` instead of a byte buffer, `ComputeHash` computes the hash in chunks, so you don't have to load the entire file in one go, which is helpful for large files.

Answer borrowed from `mgbowen` in [How do I do a SHA1 File Checksum in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993903/how-do-i-do-a-sha1-file-checksum-in-c/1993919#1993919)