# Calculate SHA1 during PostAsync with StreamContent in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, sha1

I wanted to make an HTTP POST request with a big file so I composed C# code on .net core like following:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
using (var streamContent = new StreamContent(fileStream))
{
    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    content.Add(streamContent);
    resp = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, content);
}
```

It worked well for me. But, I found that it might be happy if SHA1 can be calculated during this context then it can be used for a simple caching for the POST result.

I found some answers on SO like the following:

[How do I do a SHA1 File Checksum in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993903/how-do-i-do-a-sha1-file-checksum-in-c)

But, I have no idea how I can use this to my code.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
byte[] hash = null;

using (SHA1Managed shaForStream = new SHA1Managed())
using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
using (var streamContent = new StreamContent(fs))
{
    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    content.Add(streamContent);
    resp = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, content);
    hash = shaForStream.ComputeHash(fs);
}
```

It is not working. For example, the sha1 value is the same for different files.

I think I might need to study Stream more. Could you tell me which materials do I need to study for this problem?

p.s, There are a couple of ways to cache request and response i.e., request params and response, but I want to do it with a SHA1 way for testing. I am just curious how I can do calculate something and request POST with only one stream. I can do it by creating two file streams. :)

Comment: For what purpose are you trying to calculate the SHA1 hash? And why are you representing it as a string? What do you mean when you say 'it's definitely not working'? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: @Hintham Hi! SHA1 is going to be used for a key for caching. So, sha1 and response of the request can be used a key-value pair. It doesn't need to be representing a string. Just need sha1.

The current result of this code returns the same SHA1 value for any different kind of files.  I want to get a correct one.

FYI, there are a couple of ways to cache request and response i.e., request params and response, but I want to do with a SHA1 way for testing. This is not related to practicality.

Is it enough for you?

Comment: @Hintham I modified the code above. Thanks.