# computing git blob hash in c#

Tags: c#, git, sha1

I am trying to compute the sha1 of a file using the below method. The result is different from what is reported by "git ls-tree HEAD".  What's wrong with my code?

```
    static public string ComputeSha1()
    {
        //"blob " + <size_of_file> + "\0" + <contents_of_file>
        var content = File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\projects\myproj\Word.docx");
        var contentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(content));
        var blob = "blob " + contentLength + "\0" + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(content);

        using (SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create())
        {
            byte[] bytes = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(blob));

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                builder.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x2"));
            }
            return builder.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993903/how-do-i-do-a-sha1-file-checksum-in-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do a SHA1 File Checksum in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993903/how-do-i-do-a-sha1-file-checksum-in-c)

Comment: Stay away from `string`. Always use byte arrays. This is general advice dealing with git in languages with "unicode support"

Comment: @JohnB, @phd I actually have reviewed the link, plus others, that you provided but I decided my question is a little different.  I guess I can isolate the difference by these more specific questions:

1. Am I setting the values of content and contentLength correctly?

2. Am I concatenating properly to set the value of blob correctly?

@max630 I have seen comments somewhere else alluding to the same as yours.  I have tried a number of variations to avoid `string` without success. Would you be kind enough to make the necessary corrections to my code?