# Replace \ with \\ doesn't work for specific variable

Tags: c#, backslash

I am trying to replace a `\` with `\\` and it works with everything except the specific variable I need it to work on. Throwing the error `Illegal characters in path.` probably because it thinks \t is a character, which is tab and is therefor not allowed in a path

the variable is loaded in from a json file using Newtonsoft.Json in to a class

```
public class WebsiteConfig
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Directory { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried
`var escapedir = Regex.Replace(Directory, @"\\", @"\");` and any possible way I could form `var escapedir = Directory.Replace("\", "\\");`.

Trying `Regex.Replace("C:\test", @"\", @"\\");` (C:\test being the exact same as in Directory) worked perfectly and then inside a foreach I am trying to combine the Directory with a filename.

"Dump" of current code:

```
var json = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "config.json"));
_config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Config>(json);

foreach(WebsiteConfig website in _config.WebsiteConfigList)
{
  for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
  {
    string dir = website.Directory;
    string escapedir = Regex.Replace(dir, @"\\", @"\\\\");
    var path = Path.Combine(escapedir, "Backedup_" + i.ToString() + ".txt");
  }
}
```

And config.json:

```
{
  "WebsiteConfigList": [
    {
      "Name": "test",
      "Directory": "C:\test"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's a screenshot to show the exception:
[image: Screenshot of code]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204405/discussion-on-question-by-hackerncoder-replace-with-doesnt-work-for-specif).

Comment: @SamuelLiew Please reopen. An answer was found and I believe it is on topic. Research was done. Examples were posted. It's reproduceable.

Comment: This is not off-topic. It has been edited, it is a real problem that can be reproduced and an answer has been found. Please reopen it so that it can be answered and found by others in the future.

Comment: Your JSON file was badly produced. `\t` is a JSON escape sequence.

Comment: Yes. The anwser has found a way around that.

Comment: @Heki The question has been reopened. Please post your answer

Comment: json should be like *"Directory": "C:\\test"* for working, otherwise  .net compiler regards \ as special command `\t`

Comment: @HackerNCoder I got around to posting the answer today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem does indeed originate with `\t` but it happens during deserialisation and not with the `Path` as you might believe. There have been multiple suggestions to replace the backslash with an escaped backslash, but at that point the damage was already done:

The `C:\test` had become `C:    est` (whitespace is a tab char).

As per your requirement, altering the input file is not an option, so you have to do your escaping before deserialisation. The simplest way I can think of is:

`json = json.Replace(@"\", @"\\");`

By the way, while `Regex.Replace` is quite powerfull, `string.Replace` is adequate.

---

It doesn't look like you have large JSON files, but if you do, read a bit here on [`string.Replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146573/how-can-i-read-replace-and-write-very-large-files) on [large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273699/how-to-read-a-large-1-gb-txt-file-in-net).

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the source JSON to be `"C:\\test"` instead of `"C:\test"` then detect the tab and replace it with what you want

```
string escapedir = Regex.Replace(dir, @"\t", @"\\\\t");
```

Comment: This would cause problems with something like `C:\normal` and `C:\test\ready`. Obviously you can expand the regex to `@"\\([trn])", @"\\$1"`, but if you forget one you'll be in trouble.