# C# Parsing large flatfile data and inserting to database

Tags: c#

I have a Flat file size >1GB. I need to parse the file and insert into DB.

**Method 1:**
   Parsing and convert the flatfile to csv. 
  and then use a bulk insert in sql.

**Problem:**

Using [async](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2012/01/23/using-async-for-file-access-alan-berman.aspx) for file read, I am thrown System.OutOfMemoryException

It takes nearly 30 minutes (depends of the size) to do so.

Do I need to use efficient use of data structures to reduce the time or any other efficient methodologies  ?

Comment: Have you considered using SSIS? Alternatively, in large read/write operations in the past I have used a StreamReader to read the file, parse it and add to a DataTable, then by monitoring the size of this DataTable write to the database in stages, to avoid out of memory exceptions. So read x rows, write, clear the table, continue reading, and so on until the file is complete. This can all be done asynchronously very easily with a BackgroundWorker, or using delegates.

Comment: Just wanted to check - you're not reading the entire file into memory before parsing it, are you?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps check the [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273699/how-to-read-a-large-1-gb-txt-file-in-net). Specifically, if you are using .Net 4.0, it mentions the use of [MemoryMappedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx).

However, is there really a need to bring this in via C# if you just want to insert it into a database? Consider doing it with SQL as per the article [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/5357/bulk-insert-from-flat-file-using-transactsql/).

Comment: I wouldn't use the MemoryMappedFile if the data is being read sequentially.

Comment: @AndrewBarber agreed. Having reread the question is appears the goal is to simply get the data inserted into the database, which probably requires a different approach altogether :)

Comment: @Nick: Yeah I could not use MemoryMappedFile. Not enough storage is available to process MemoryMappedViewStream command for the file.

Comment: @Yoshi: Yeah no problem. Is there a reason to pull this into C# at all? Or are you simply looking to get the data into the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple FileStream with BinaryReader like this

```
Boolean isSaving = true, savedOk = false;                  
new Task(new Action(() =>
{
    try
    {
        string fileName = "filename.txt";
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            long size = new FileInfo(fileName).Length;
            int bytesPerRead = (int)(size < 512000 ? size : 512000);
            byte[] past = br.ReadBytes(bytesPerRead);
            int offset = 0;

            while (offset < size)
            {
                //TODO - SAVE YOUR BYTE ARRAY TO DB USING WCF OR LOCAL PROC 

                offset = offset + bytesPerRead;
                bytesPerRead = (int)(size - offset < 512000 ? size - offset : 512000);
                past = br.ReadBytes(bytesPerRead);                                    
            }
            savedOk = true;
       }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { savedOk = false; }
    isSaving = false;                        

 })).Start();
 while (isSaving) 
 { 
    //DOUPDATES 
 };
```