# Reading the last changes of a text file after FileSystemWatcher detects change

Tags: c#, logging, io, monitoring, filesystemwatcher

Relating to my earlier post: [Smartest way to monitor log-files in realtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17090428/2310637)
I want a FileSystemWatcher to detect changes of a text file (logfile) and afterwards I want it to show me the latest changes!

They are big files >50bm, and a full scan almost every second is very time-consuming.
I though `.last()` could help, but this code only returns the last row:

```
 File.ReadText(@"C:\Filename.txt").Last();
```

I need some code that can continue reading from the last spot and just determine and returns the changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only appending data at the end of the file, you could save in memory the position of the **last read byte**, and read from this position to the end of the file each time you're notified the file has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

`FileSystemWatcher` won't exactly do what you want. It sees changes at the directory level. Once the file changes it has no history of it's previous contents. Calling `Last()` on `File.ReadText()` also has no concept of the files previous state which is why it just returns the last row.

I think the best approach would be to save the EOF's position then each time the FSW raises a file changed event you would read from previous EOF position to the new EOF then update the variable which stores the EOF's position.