# How to read specific amount of data from a large file

Tags: c#

I have a 1GB file containing 1 string per line.

I have to read the first 100MB such that if the boundary falls in the middle of the string, the whole of the last line gets included in the result.

What is the best way to accomplish tis in C#?

Comment: How precise does it need to be? Would it matter if you read a few more lines than you're meant to? (It would make it *much* simpler.)

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273699/how-to-read-a-large-1-gb-txt-file-in-net

Comment: @Jon would like it to be precise...but please propose your solution..would like to know alternatives

Comment: @VyacheslavYudanov: I don't see how that's a duplicate.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate IMHO, but it gives some very good pointers.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a `StreamReader` to read the lines, but check the `Position` on the underlying stream:

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
using (var reader = File.OpenText("file.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while (reader.BaseStream.Position < DataLimit &&
           (line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        lines.Add(line);
    }
}
```

There are two problems here:

- The `StreamReader` is likely to buffer data, so the `Stream` will actually be further on than the data you've read. You'll need to add some extra buffer to your limit in order to cope with this, and even then it's still not going to be very precise.
- Calling `Position` on each line is likely to slow things down significantly.

Another alternative is to copy as much data as you definitely want to consume into a `MemoryStream`, then keep reading (and converting to text) until you find the next line break, then appending that final partial-line data to the `MemoryStream` and finally creating a `StreamReader` around the `MemoryStream`, but again that's quite fiddly.

Yet another alternative would be to create some kind of "length-limiting" stream wrapper where you'd set the limit large enough to definitely include the last line - again, this would overread somewhat, potentially.