# Fast way to change txt file and save it

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, filestream, streamreader

I have txt file(65mb)i need to read line by line and change each line,
For example i have many lines

```
User=value Password=value  Phone=123456789
User=value Password=value  Phone=123456789
User=value Password=value  Phone=123456789
```

and i need to change first number of credit card/Phone to*(security reason), and get text like this and save it, or just to change origin text file.

```
User=value Password=value  Phone=*****6789
User=value Password=value  Phone=*****6789
User=value Password=value  Phone=*****6789
```

I build new string and add to there line(changed) by line than save, but it take me to many time this is my code

```
 string NewPath = "";
        string lineOfText;
        string NewTextFile = "";
        using (var filestream = new FileStream(FilePath,
                             FileMode.Open,
                             FileAccess.Read,
                             FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            var file = new StreamReader(filestream, Encoding.UTF8, true, 128);

            while ((lineOfText = file.ReadLine()) != null)//here i reading line by line
            {
                NewTextFile += lineOfText.Substring(0, 124) + "************" +
                lineOfText.Substring(136, lineOfText.Length - 136);
                NewTextFile += Environment.NewLine;//here i make new string
            }
        }

        NewPath = FilePatharr[1] + "\\temp.txt";
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(NewPath, NewTextFile);//here i save him
```

Do any one know better way to do this,my code is taking to long to save this big file.
**UPDATE**

Why do i get -2 for this question? Whats wrong with this question? I see here only wrong answers about how to pass sensitive data and more things that not belong to this questions When the question was -->Fast way to change txt file and save it

Any way i find out how to do this speed of saving file speedUp from 100kb\sec to 3MB\sec now it taking me 20sec and not 20min like before

Comment: I am not.I am downloading this file from CyberArk File Exchange, the Company is making this files and put them there, my goal is to open file  remove/change the first(5) number to ******6789

Comment: Instead of buffering NewTextFile into a string, you should write it in new text file and rename it after. You will avoid losing your data if your application is killed at `File.WriteAllText`

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4274051/1029287) answers how to read and handle a large file, writing it back should be trivial.

Comment: When i said Company i did't mean that is my company, it is customer Company they send to as files like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your primary problem here is that you're appending to a string. And that gets expensive very quickly. You should be able to process that 65 MB in about five seconds. Here's what I would do:

```
string outputFileName = "temp.txt";
using (var outputFile = new StreamWriter(outputFileName))
{
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(inputFileName))
    {
        var newLine = line.Substring(0, 124) + "************" +
                    line.Substring(136, lineOfText.Length - 136);
        outputFile.WriteLine(newLine);
    }
}
```

This is going to be a lot faster than appending strings. If you really want to do it all in memory, then use a `StringBuilder`. Instead of

```
string NewTextFile = "";
```

Use

```
StringBuilder NewTextFile = new StringBuilder();
```

And when you're composing the output, replace the string concatenation with:

```
NewTextFile.AppendLine(
    lineOfText.Substring(0, 124) + "************" +
    lineOfText.Substring(136, lineOfText.Length - 136));
```

Finally, to write it to the file:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(NewPath, NewTextFile.ToString());
```

Comment: Your answer 3 times faster thanx

Answer (score 3):

You could keep `WriteAllLines` and use `ReadAllLines`:

1. [`ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.file.readalllines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get all lines as an array of strings
2. Enumerate the array and use `string.Replace` to replace its content, line by line
3. [`WriteAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and overwrite existing file

Or you could use stream reader/writer and read/write line by line. You currently are building a string with millions of concatenations, that's the performance issue.

That being said, you probably have an obvious security issue here. Why was critical information such as credit card numbers stored as plain text in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static string ChangeCardNumber(string FilePath, string txtFileName)
        {
            string NewPath = "";
            string lineOfText;
            string NewTextFile = "";
            NewPath = FilePatharr[0] + "\\temp_" + txtFileName;

            using (var filestream = new FileStream(FilePath,
                                 FileMode.Open,
                                 FileAccess.Read,
                                 FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                var file = new StreamReader(filestream, Encoding.UTF8, true, 128);
                System.IO.File.Create(NewPath).Close();
                int res = 0;
                while ((lineOfText = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    res++;

                    if (!lineOfText.Contains("EOF"))
                    {
                        NewTextFile += lineOfText.Substring(0, 124) + "************" +
                        lineOfText.Substring(136, lineOfText.Length - 136);
                        NewTextFile += Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                    if (res % 200 == 0 || lineOfText.Contains("EOF"))//check if endline and if in NewTextFile 200lines
                    {
                        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(NewPath, NewTextFile);
                        NewTextFile = "";
                    }
                }

            }



            return NewPath;

        }
```

Answer (score -6):

Well I Guess You Could Do It Another Way And This Way Is The Way I Use For All of my saving needs.
if you want to save it all at the same time then this would work! or you could have it loaded in VARIABLES and then save it but this is the code to save it. it is very simple and easy to edit

There You Go

Basic Code To Add A New Line With Text

```
echo your text here >>filename.txt
```

For Explaination Please Visit The DropBox Link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nufkecx1b8088cu/HOW%20TO%20USE%20THIS.txt

Comment: One this isn't c# and two don't include links to your personal dropbox in answers, it will become a dead link in the future and it more security questions on top of those from the original question, oh and #3 it doesn't answer the question