# Extracting data from a large file with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a close to 800 MB file which consists of several (header followed by content). 
Header looks something like this `M=013;X=rast;645.jpg` while content is binary of the jpg file.

So the file looks something like this

```
M=013;X=rast;645.jpgNULœDüŠˆ.....M=217;X=rast;113.jpgNULÿñÿÿ&åbÿås....M=217;X=rast;1108.jpgNUL]_ÿ×ÉcË/...
```

The header can occur in one line or across two lines.

I need to parse this file and basically pop out the several jpg images.

Since this is too big a file, please suggest an efficient way? I was hoping to use StreamReader but do not have much experience with regular expressions to use with it.

Comment: Here's something to get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273699/how-to-read-a-large-1-gb-txt-file-in-net  as for reading the file, that's your job no?  Perhaps post what you've tried & what errors you run into and we can help further.  Otherwise you can always hire a developer to do it for you!

Comment: What do you need out of the header? And does the header always end with ".jpg" ?

Comment: I wouldn't use regex for this. Maybe look into the jpg spec to see if you can extract a length from it..

Comment: What do you mean - "across two lines"?  Do you mean the header is divided by a carriage return and/or line feed?

Comment: If it were me I'd use something like `[^;]+\.jpg` in EditPadPro, which can handle multi-gigabyte files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegEx:
`/(M=.+?;X=.+?;.+?\.jpg)(.+?(?=(?1)|$))/gs` **with recursion (not supported in .NET)*

.NET RegEx workaround:
**`/(M=.+?;X=.+?;.+?\.jpg)(.+?(?=M=.+?;X=.+?;.+?\.jpg|$))/gs`**
*replaced the `(?1)` recursion group with the contents inside the 1st capture group*

Live demo and Explanation of RegExp: http://regex101.com/r/nQ3pE0/1

You'll want to use the 2nd capture group for binary contents, the 1st group will match the header and the expression needs it to know where to stop.

**edited in italic*

Comment: Thanks for your help. This doesn't seem to be a valid C# regex as it is giving me error - unrecognized grouping constructs. any thoughts? I am using something like this MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(input, @"(M=.+?;X=.+?;.+?\.jpg)(.+?(?=(?1)|$))", RegexOptions.Singleline);

Comment: Yes, edited the post, I wasn't aware .NET does not understand recursion... friends help at pointing out stuff :) See now if the new one helps