# reading a text file its size (nearly 4 miga )c#

Tags: c#, file, text, stream, writer

I write a code to read many text files and grouped them in one file called  (all.txt), after that I read all.txt file to count the word frequency, and the result appears in richtextbox. the code work well but the problem when I run the program, part of result appears then the program is hang without responding. I think that may be from memory, my computer RAM is 4 GB  any help would be appreciated.
note:my code work well in small text file.here's part of my code :

```
  StreamWriter w=new StreamWriter(@"C:\documents\all.txt");
            w.Write(all);
            w.Close();
```

Comment: You talk about reading but your code is for writing ... Are you asking about latency due to loading 4 megabytes of text into a Windows Form RichTextBox control?

Comment: 1) What's "miga"? Figure out if you're talking about megabytes or gigabytes and fix your question. 2) Why did you post a code snippet of writing to a file when your question is about reading?

Comment: Are you trying to update the RichTextBox as you read the file?  Give us more details and some code that is relevant to your question.

Comment: thank you all for your comments, I think that the problem not in writing or reading the files instead it's in memory because when I read just  a few files the program works without any problem so, I wonder if anyone could help me about that.

Answer (score -1):

If your problem is reading a large file, try using MemoryMappedFile as indicated in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273699/how-to-read-a-large-1-gb-txt-file-in-net)