# Advanced TextReader to EndOfFile

Tags: c#, .net

I have a textReader that in a specific instance I want to be able to advance to the end of file quickly so other classes that might hold a reference to this object will not be able to call tr.ReadLine() without getting a null.

This is a large file.  I cannot use TextReader.ReadToEnd() as it will often lead to an OutOfMemoryException

I thought I would ask the community if there was a way SEEK the stream without using TextReader.ReadToEnd() which returns a string of all data in the file.

Current method, inefficient.
The following example code is a mock up.  Obviously I am not opening a file with an if statement directly following it asking if I want to read to the end.

```
TextReader tr = new StreamReader("Largefile");
if(needToAdvanceToEndOfFile)
{
    while(tr.ReadLine() != null) { }
}
```

Desired solution (Note this code block contains fake 'concept' methods or methods that cannot be used due to risk of outofmemoryexception)

```
TextReader tr = new StreamReader("Largefile");
if(needToAdvanceToEndOfFile)
{
    tr.SeekToEnd(); // A method that does not return anything. This method does not exist.
    // tr.ReadToEnd() not acceptable as it can lead to OutOfMemoryException error as it is very large file.
}
```

A possible alternative is to read through the file in bigger chunks using                 tr.ReadBlock(args).

I poked around ((StreamReader)tr).BaseStream but could not find anything that worked.

As I am new to the community I figured I would see if someone knew the answer off the top of their head.

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161895/reading-large-text-files-with-streams-in-c

Comment: If I am reading the link you posted correctly, the only item I can see that might apply is the tr.Read() / tr.ReadBlock() which would allow me to read through the file in bigger chunks.  I did mention that as a possibility above.

I'm hoping someone knows a way to advance the stream to the end using ((StreamReader)tr).BaseStream or another method that does not use loops.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to discard any buffered data if you have read any file content - since data is buffered you might get content even if you seek the underlying stream to the end - working example:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
string sampleLine = sr.ReadLine();

//discard all buffered data and seek to end
sr.DiscardBufferedData();
sr.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
```

The problem as mentioned in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.basestream%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is

> The StreamReader class buffers input from the underlying stream when
>   you call one of the Read methods. If you manipulate the position of
>   the underlying stream after reading data into the buffer, the position
>   of the underlying stream might not match the position of the internal
>   buffer. **To reset the internal buffer, call the DiscardBufferedData
>   method**

Comment: This worked great!  Thank both you and Jalal Aldeen Saa'd for your assistance!

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
```

Test:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"Your Large File"))
{
    reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);

    int read = reader.Read();//read will be -1 since you are at the end of the stream
}
```

**Edit:** Test it with your code:

```
using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader("C:\\test.txt"))//test.txt is a file that has data and lines
{
    ((StreamReader)tr).BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);

    string foo = tr.ReadLine();
    Debug.WriteLine(foo ?? "foo is null");//foo is null
    int read = tr.Read();
    Debug.WriteLine(read);//-1
}
```

Comment: Already did.  ((StreamReader)tr).BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);  does not work.  tr.ReadLine() returns string data still.

Comment: I use `StreamReader` and test it with a file, the `read` will have `-1` **Edit:** I even test it will `
                ((StreamReader)tr).BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);` and the `read` after that returns `-1`

Comment: I just did this test (code snippet)

if ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.StartsWith("#%GroupName=") || line.StartsWith("#%SetName="))
                {
                    ((StreamReader)tr).BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
                    string s = tr.ReadLine();
                    // returned #%Columns=5

Comment: I test it and it returns `null`.

Comment: I do not know what to say.  I do it on my end using the code above and tr.ReadLine() still returns a string.

Comment: I test it with your code and the results is as expected. "check the answer update"

Comment: Your method only works if the file stream is at the beginning.  That is why it was not working.
I am in the middle of the file when I need to seek to the end.  I tried ((StreamReader)tr).BaseStream.Seek(((StreamReader)tr).BaseStream.Position, SeekOrigin.End) in case the first argument was asking for the current offset position in the file, and that did not work either.

Comment: Yes you are right I tested it, I will try to think in way around it

Comment: The `StreamReader` class buffers part of the file.  Unless you want to write your own StreamReader class, you'll have this problem.