# how to determine if a c# application is busy?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use Progress bar during loading an xml File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099149/how-to-use-progress-bar-during-loading-an-xml-file)

I have an XML file and there are almost 200.000 records in the XML file.
I load those records to the DataTable like below.

```
string file = "C:\\records.xml";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.ReadXml(file);
```

when this process works application waits until loading data to datatable.
So, i want to use this time. And i want to show to user processbar while loading data to the datatable.
How can i do it?

Comment: Why you have to load 200.000 records into memory?

Comment: There's only so much patience a user has to stare at a glacially incrementing progress bar.  She'll put up with it for no more than 5 seconds and fires up Solitaire.  Hide your user interface and use a NotifyIcon to display a balloon when the job got done.  Using a handful of different icons that show progress is a nicety.

Answer (score 1):

It is always better practice to do long blocking operations on a different thread, using a **[`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)**.

You can update the progressBar on the UI thread using the **[`ReportProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx)** method. **[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/83317/BackgroundWorker-and-ProgressBar-demo)**'s an example.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But could you show an example please.

Comment: @namco There is a link to an example in the answer. I didn't notice earlier, but your question seems to be the same as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099149/how-to-use-progress-bar-during-loading-an-xml-file-in-c)