# fastest way of reading values from a comma separated text files with varying number of columns

Tags: c#, .net, csv

[image]

what is the most efficient way as in speed of reading values in a text file (see sample screen shot above) into an excel or .csv file using c#?.

The first row will always have column names and in this sample they are 6 columns but that's not the standard. In another file, the columns could be 4 or 9.

Skipping those blank rows would also be nice.

NOTE that the text files can be as big as 2 or 4 GBs.

Thanks.

Comment: Use one of the already available csv-parser instead of reinventing the wheel. Here is one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader Btw, why don't you use a database instead of fiddling around with 4 GB text files?

Comment: `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser` is part of the framework. Available immeadiately if you can tolerate polluting your references. I don't know how fasted it is.

Comment: @TimSchmelter the files are Log files generated by a monitoring system i have no control over.

Comment: I highly recommend using `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`. It's going to be plenty fast enough. Your limiting factor is going to be disk I/O, not the speed of the CSV parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `BufferedStream` which is a buffer for an existing stream, i.e. `FileStream` which will help performance.

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
{
   string line;
   while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
   {

   }
}
```

Sources:

[Reading large text files with streams in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161895/reading-large-text-files-with-streams-in-c-sharp)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream.aspx