# Read line by line a large text file and search for a string

Tags: c#, string, file

I am currently developing an application that reads a text file of about 50000 lines. For each line, I need to check if it contains a specific String.

At the moment, I use the conventional `System.IO.StreamReader` to read my file line by line.

The problem is that the size of the text file changes each time. I made several test performance and I noticed that when the file size increase, the more time it will take to read a line.

#### For example :

Reading a txt file that contains 5000 lines : 0:40
Reading a txt file that contains 10000 lines : 2:54

It take 4 times longer to read a file 2 times larger. I can't imagine how much time it will takes to read a 100000 lines file.

Here's my code :

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(this.MyPath))
{
     while (streamReader.Peek() > 0)
     {
          string line = streamReader.ReadLine();

          if (line.Contains(Resources.Constants.SpecificString)
          {
               // Do some action with the string.
          }
     }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the situation: bigger File = more time to read a single line?

Comment: `string.Contains` is not very efficient for this type of search.

Comment: Are you searching a few files, multiple times? Or Multiple files 1 time?

Comment: Using regular expression on the text file is much faster and much more efficient.

Comment: A compiled RegEx should perform much better.

Comment: I am looking through one file only.

Comment: I doubt that a RegEx is faster that a simple call to Contains.

Comment: You've never used it.

Comment: did you try with "string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt"); " and then loop through array... didn't try, but maybe is faster.

Comment: Yeah I tried and it take the same time.

Comment: @DavorMlinaric `File.ReadAllLines` will read the whole thing into memory - not a desirable thing, if you wish to process things line-by-line.

Comment: The "Do some action" portion may be the culprit here. Did you try replacing it with a simple counter, and then comparing the timing of 5000 vs. 10000 lines? The time should grow linearly, unless you've got some disproportionally long strings in the second file.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I use the same file for the timing tests. I only copied all of the 5000 rows twice. the time increases exponentially and this is my problem

Comment: I doubt if you keep doubling the size of the file you'll see a an exponential growth in the time taken. It *should* be approximately O(N), since only linear operations are being done. I've no idea why the big slowdown when doubling the size of the file - does it contain similar data to the first file? What is the "DoSomeAction()"? I agree with dasblinkenlight - it might be the culprit.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161895/reading-large-text-files-with-streams-in-c-sharp)? He is reading much larger files then you. He is suggesting a `BufferedStream` to improve the read speed

Comment: it is what I thought too. I find it strange that the reading time is exponential. The do some action is only a piece of code that allows me to search through another .csv file in order to find the corresponding line. If the line is found, I added it into a datatable.

Comment: @Sebastien The time does not look exponential, it looks quadratic. Try 15000 lines, and see if it's nine times the 5000-line's time to prove this suggestion. The next thing to try would be shortening the line for which you are searching (i.e. the `SpecificString`) to a single character, and trying this experiment again. The timing of `Contains` is `O(m*n)`, where `m` is the length of the line of text, and `n` is the length of the string being searched.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
var toSearch = Resources.Constants.SpecificString;
foreach (var str in File.ReadLines(MyPath).Where(s => s.Contains(toSearch))) {
    // Do some action with the string
}
```

This avoids accessing the resources on each iteration by caching value before the loop. If this does not help, try writing your own `Contains` based on an advanced string searching algorithm, such as the [KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).

---

Note: be sure to use [File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which reads lines lazily (unlike similarly looking `File.ReadAllLines` that reads all lines at once).

Comment: Using a variable to store the search time will improve performance, but using a LINQ query instead of a simple if statement will decrease it because lambda functions are quite expensive.

Comment: @Dirk Microsoft's team optimized the heck out of lambdas, so they are not expensive at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RegEx.IsMatch` and you should see some performance improvements.

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(this.MyPath))
{
 var regEx = new Regex(MyPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);

 while (streamReader.Peek() > 0)
 {
      string line = streamReader.ReadLine();

      if (regEx.IsMatch(line))
      {
           // Do some action with the string.
      }
 }
}
```

Please remember to use a compiled RegEx, however. Here's a [pretty good article](http://nathanbrixius.wordpress.com/2010/06/03/which-is-faster-regex-ismatch-or-string-contains/) with some benchmarks you can look at.

Happy coding!