# How to open a file in HEX regardless of its extension and size?

Tags: c#, wpf, hex, hexdump

I'm new in C# and don't know which way I should use to work with big files.
I tried `ReadAllBytes()` method and `BitConverter` and then show it in TextBlock but it takes a very long time and my program freezes.
I used Be.Hex editor and this one opens any file instantly!

I also tried `FileStream` and `Read` method and it takes a long time too. I really have no idea how to make it right.

```
using (FileStream fstream = File.OpenRead(path)) 
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[_fileStream.Length];
    fstream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    string hexValues = BitConverter.ToString(buffer);
}
```

Comment: You don't. The secret of those editors is to *not* load all of the file into memory.

Comment: `fstream.Seek` to the area you want, then `Read` a length of bytes. Use async where possible.

Comment: [Processing a large file in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16233002/982149) or [How to read a large (1 GB) txt file in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4273699/982149) didn't help? This may also be of interest: [Memory-Mapped Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files)

Comment: @jdweng Either I missed something or OP is not (only) looking how to open XML files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't read the entire file into memory but rather leverage `Stream` to lazily load and display the file in chunks on demand, and WPF's virtualization capabilities to ensure the UI is not overwhelmed. Here's an extremely simple example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        int rowLength = 32;
        var str = File.OpenRead("c:\\MyFile.bin");
        int rows = (int)Math.Ceiling(str.Length / (double)rowLength);

        var rowVMs = Enumerable.Range(0, rows).Select(row =>
        {
            return new HexRow(str, row * rowLength, rowLength);
        });
        this.HexDump = new ObservableCollection<HexRow>(rowVMs);

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<HexRow> HexDump
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

public class HexRow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Stream _source;
    int _start;
    int _count;
    bool _isLoading;
    string _HexString;

    public HexRow(Stream source, int start, int count)
    {
        _source = source;
        _start = start;
        _count = count;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    public string HexString
    {
        get
        {
            if (_HexString == null && !_isLoading)
                LoadHexStringAsync();
            return _HexString;
        }
        set
        {
            this._HexString = value;
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(
                this, 
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(HexString)));
        }
    }

    private async void LoadHexStringAsync()
    {
        _isLoading = true;
        byte[] data = new byte[_count];
        _source.Seek(_start, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        await _source.ReadAsync(data, 0, _count);
        this.HexString = BitConverter.ToString(data);
        _isLoading = false;
    }
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        x:Name="_mainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=_mainWindow, Path=HexDump}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock FontFamily="Courier New"
                           Text="{Binding HexString, IsAsync=True}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

In a real-world scenario you would need to build your own custom viewer that employed `VirtualizingStackPanel` rather than using a `ListBox`. For more efficiency you'd probably also load in bigger chunks than just one row at a time. But this should give you a good starting point.

Comment: I used your code but changed row length to 4096 and it opened 4 Gb file on 200 ms!