# Putting length to 0 for OutOfMemoryException of StringBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net, stringbuilder

I have a block of code which gets a file and appends require data as shown below:

```
var srBuilder = new StringBuilder();
using (var file = new StreamReader(document.FullSourcePath, Encoding.ASCII))
            {
                while (!file.EndOfStream)
                {                 
                    var bytess = new char[numBytes];
                    file.ReadBlock(bytess , 0, bytess.Length);
                    srBuilder.Append(buff);
                }

                document.Document += srBuilder.ToString();  ////Exception occures here
            }
```

But when file is more than 200 MB then its throwing OutofMemoryException.

What i thought is to make length of string builder to zero as below:

```
 while (!file.EndOfStream)
        {  
            srBuilder.Length = 0;      //// Here         
            var bytess = new char[numBytes];
            file.ReadBlock(bytess , 0, bytess.Length);
            srBuilder.Append(buff);
        }
```

Is it best solution or anything else is required?

Comment: Your code does not make sense to me. Can you explain in plain English what you want to happen?

Comment: Its fetching file from path -> reading until end of stream occurs and then appending everything at last.

Comment: Why not use File.ReadAllLines...?

Comment: At 32 bits it is very difficult to have CONTIGUOUS space for a `string` of 400mb (your 200mb of ASCII file in .NET will be a 400mb unicode `string`, with each character 2 bytes). Try at 64 bits (should load without problems) or try finding a different algorithm where you don't need loading a 200mb file in memory.

Comment: Is your question _"How can I have a ~200~ 400 MB string in memory"_? Then the counter-question is _"Why do you think you need that?"_.

Comment: file is loaded with all important information and it is not the case everytime @CodeCaster

Comment: its not the case everytime @xanatos it happens once in a while

Comment: @Neel Program for the worst case, hope for the best case.

Comment: its all about StringBuilder. have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769447/interesting-outofmemoryexception-with-stringbuilder

Comment: **In general** you don't load a full file of unknown size in memory. You load it one row at a time, you parse and use that row, you forget of that row and go to the next row.

Comment: then nvoigt answer makes sence @xanatos?

Comment: Why do you think `srBuilder.Length = 0` will solve anything? This will throw away any data in the stringbuilder. Please explain why you think you need the entire file in memory at once. Hint: you probably don't.

Comment: but its clearly metioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769447/interesting-outofmemoryexception-with-stringbuilder and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192512/how-can-i-clear-or-empty-a-stringbuilder @CodeCaster and let us say its one of the requirement to store then?

Comment: Setting the length to 0 is effectively clearing the stringbuilder's contents. You cannot do that, as you're then simply throwing away data. That's the problem with copy-pasting code you don't understand. If it is a "requirement" that the entire text file needs to be loaded in-memory at once (which is not a real requirement, but might be your interpretation of it), then you have a problem: you can not reliably do this. Explain what you do with `document.Document` afterwards that makes you think you need this, then a real solution can be suggested.

Comment: the thing is that here in code "numBytes" comes from config file and its normally 10 MB at once @CodeCaster

Comment: I think you don't understand what I'm trying to tell you. **You simply cannot read a file that large in memory at once** (at least not at 32 bit), **and you shouldn't want to**. It is entirely irrelevant to that problem that the read buffer size comes from a configuration file. See [Read Big TXT File, Out of Memory Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415916/), [Out of memory exception reading and writing text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381474/) and so on.

Comment: i am not reading entire file but chunks at a time then appending and creating string at the end @CodeCaster. if you have any useful link then share

Comment: That **is** reading the entire file in memory at once. By appending, you're letting a variable grow to the size of the file (even more so, since UTF-16 is used internally, and causing a lot of garbage in the meantime because strings are immutable). That you append this data in chunks is irrelevant, and does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ultimate goal is to assign a 200 MB ASCII file to the `document.Document` member variable, which I assume is of type string.

Long story short: you cannot do this, and need to reconsider your approach.

One way or another, this requirement of yours will require 400 MB of contiguous memory (given strings are `char[]` arrays of UTF-16 characters, weighing 2 bytes per character), which is nigh impossible to obtain in a 32 bit process, which the `OutOfMemoryException` that the runtime throws is trying to tell you.

Any "trick" you're going to find is going to have its drawbacks.

- Reading the file in chunks doesn't matter, as the end result is the same: the final string will still require 400 MB of contiguous memory.
- Setting the `StringBuilder`'s `Length` to 0, found through Googling "C# StringBuilder OutOfMemoryException", will make the exception go away, but only cause the last chunk of the file to be assigned to `document.Document`. It's safe to say you don't want that as well.
- Changing the project to run only on 64 bit machines **might** be an option, but most likely won't (hardware and other dependencies), and is a dirty workaround that hides the actual problem, and that is like applying a band-aid to a blown-off leg: you're ignoring the fatal design mistake. One day someone is going to feed your app a 2 GB file, and you're back to square one.

You need to **stream** the file, and process it line by line.

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(filename))
{
    // process line
}
```

Comment: by the way what if i still need everything in document.Document then?

Comment: thing is whole code is already written and i am just there to handle 200 MB file case :/

Comment: Somebody gave me a 5 liter bucket and tells me to go get 200 liter of water with it. What do I tell them?

Comment: My point is: whatever it is you're doing with `document.Document` must be changed to support streaming. You simply cannot assign 400 MB of data to it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you made it that complicated. All you need is a single line:

```
document.Document += File.ReadAllText(document.FullSourcePath, Encoding.ASCII);
```

If this throws an exception, then yes, maybe you don't have enough memory.

Comment: i had 50 rounds of testing and it threw exception once. is it problem? i had some debuggers in that case