# Memory exceeding while reading from stream writing to another one

Tags: c#, memory, stream, out-of-memory, buffer

I am reading data from one stream and writing to another.
The file I want to copy is 1.4 GB of size.
Why is the memory used by my program growing all the time while reading and writing.
How can i prevent an out of memory exception?

```
//Write data from URL
HttpWebRequest webRequestWrite = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(WriteUrl);

webRequestWrite.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false;
webRequestWrite.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;

webRequestWrite.Method = "PUT";
using (Stream responseStreamWrite = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
{

   int chunkSize = 4194304;
   byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
   int bytesRead = 0;
   int totalBytes = 0;

   //Read data from URL
   HttpWebRequest webRead = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ReadUrl);
   webRead.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false;
   webRead.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
   using (WebResponse webResponseread = webRead.GetResponse())
   using (Stream responseStreamRead = webResponseread.GetResponseStream())
   {
      while ((bytesRead = responseStreamRead.Read(buffer, 0, chunkSize)) > 0)
      {
        totalBytes += bytesRead;
        responseStreamWrite.Write(buffer.Take(bytesRead).ToArray(), 0, bytesRead);
        responseStreamWrite.Flush();
        responseStreamRead.Flush();
      }
   }

   responseStreamWrite.Flush();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading large text files with streams in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161895/reading-large-text-files-with-streams-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Are you getting OOM exception or just unhappy about memory usage? Note that you should probably be using `Stream.CopyTo` or even `Stream.CopyToAsync` instead of inventing your own.

Comment: Can you set `SendChunked` to true on the `webRequestWrite` request? You may need to set the ContentLength as well.

Comment: @mike z SendChunked did the trick. Please post it as answer and I will accept it. Thx. The memory consumption is now at 11 Mb. You do not need to set the ContentLenght

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting `SendChunked` to true on the request that you are writing to (`webRequestWrite`). Otherwise, the request will internally buffered until the request stream is closed, so the entire request can be sent as a single message. The underlying resource needs to support this transfer mode and may require you to set the content length first. The internal buffering here is different from `AllowWriteStreamBuffering` which buffers data for resending in the case of redirection or authentication requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing Stream with BufferedStream.

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream.read(v=vs.110).aspx
```

Might be duplicate question:

[Reading large text files with streams in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161895/reading-large-text-files-with-streams-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question: OP can't pick type of the stream at all (coming from the WebRequest) and already reading in huge chunks.

Comment: Where are you seeing the out of memory exception. Is it at this step bytesRead = responseStreamRead.Read(buffer, 0, chunkSize) ?