# Reading only one specific element from a CSV in C#

Tags: c#, csv

I am fairly new to C# and I've been wrecking my head with a problem. I need to read one particular line/position from a CSV file (2nd line, 4th column), which ALWAYS hold the data I expect.

*(If you're curious: this CSV file is a report and the first 3 lines are a header. The field in question holds a date)*

Here is what I (sort of) started with after doing some research (and with my n00b C# skills):

```
        dt = new DataTable();
        string[] csvRows = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(origFilePath);
        dt.Columns.Add(csvRows[0]);

        for (int x = 1; x < 2; x++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(csvRows[x]);
        }
        dt.Rows[0][0].ToString(); // must modify [0][0]
```

Thing is, the file can be quite big, so I don't think I need to read the entire file and setting it into a table object for then retrieving that value.

I'm sure there must be a better way?!

Can someone please advise? Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
P.

Comment: Can you add a simple version of your csv file and show what you want to read? Probably you can directly read `mth` line and get `nth` column with a `String.Split(',')`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading large text files with streams in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161895/reading-large-text-files-with-streams-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One-liner:

```
var myValue = System.IO.File.ReadLines(origFilePath).Skip(1).First().Split(',')[3];
```

I'm sure it's not the optimal way (I not even tested), but should do the trick.

Don't forget to import the Linq namespace (`using System.Linq;`).

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines("file").Skip(1).First().Split(',')[3]`

Comment: Fixed. Thanks @ArghyaC !

Comment: Wait, but ReadAllLines still reads the entire file. You should use ReadLines which does it in a lazy way..

Comment: Changed from `ReadAllLines` to `ReadLines`. Thanks @MaorVeitsman !

Comment: Folks thank you for your help. Just did a simple console app to try this and it works beautifully -- indeed with a single line!

Comment: In some cases, CSV value can be complicated and be in double quotes having comma inside ( value1, value2, "value 3, with comma", value4 ). This simple solution will fail in this case.

Comment: You are right but this particular case this is never going to happen because this particular 'cell' ALWAYS has the values in the way we expect. They are system generated.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a lazy method to get what you need.  Lazy means avoiding reading the entire file to get the right line.

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
{
    var i = 0;
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (i == 4) //4th position = 5th line (3 header lines plus 2 data lines)
        {
            return line.split(',')[3];
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Code is partially ripped from here:
[Reading large text files with streams in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161895/reading-large-text-files-with-streams-in-c-sharp)

Alternatively, you can do:

```
var i = 0;
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(filepath))
{
    if (i == 4)
    {
        return line.split(',')[3];
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: @pmdci Easy does it, I meant the code I provided which you would have seen had you followed my link instead of being defensive from the start, its from the top answer of the link I provided with your logic added.  Jesus, you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use oledb to read csv without opening.  You can modify SQL statement to retrieve only column you need.

```
public class CSVReader
    {

        public DataSet ReadCSVFile(string fullPath, bool headerRow)
        {

            string path = fullPath.Substring(0, fullPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            string filename = fullPath.Substring(fullPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(fullPath))
                {
                    string ConStr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}" + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR={1};FMT=Delimited\\\"", path, headerRow ? "Yes" : "No");
                    string SQL = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", filename);
                    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, ConStr);
                    adapter.Fill(ds, "TextFile");
                    ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Table1";
                }
                foreach (DataColumn col in ds.Tables["Table1"].Columns)
                {
                    col.ColumnName = col.ColumnName.Replace(" ", "_");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return ds;
        }
    }​
```

Answer (score 0):

Read line from CSV file, go directly to 15th position and get the value.
Refer below c# code

```
namespace DBCreateTags
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"T:\test.csv"))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    var values = line.Split(',')[15];

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```