# How to read large one line text file?

Tags: c#

I have a really large text file, lets say 500MB. I know we can use `File.ReadLines()` to read the file. It will iterate the text file line by line, thus saving the memory greatly. But what if my file is a single line? I have a text file contain a base64string, when I tried to use `File.ReadLines()`, I got an 'Out of Memory' exception.

How do I solve this?

Comment: BinaryReader? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161895/reading-large-text-files-with-streams-in-c-sharp

Comment: What is the purpose of the file? Do you really need to read it all in one go?

Comment: 500Mb isn't all that large. You could compile the file in 64-bit mode to avoid the out-of-memory issue.

Comment: Do the reading yourself using a Stream and a StreamReader

Comment: Theres even a stream transformer for base64, making streaming easier in this case: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.frombase64transform(v=vs.110).aspx (use in combination with CryptoStream)