# How can I modify a 11GB .csv file in C#?

Tags: c#, csv, self-modifying, bigdata

I have a 15 million rows .csv file. It includes some rows where only hyphens are. But impossible to open this file with excel, notepad or notepad++. Therefore I thought that to modify it in C# (first read in, than write out as a new modified file where hyphens rows are not founded).

How can I code it in the easiest way?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Why do you have a 15 million row csv file?  Who do you expect to make sense of that?

Comment: ok it depends on how you want to modify it, but you can read any file line by line, and write out a new one... and then move it over the place of the old.

Comment: There are libraries for opening CSV files (like https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)... You'll have to do it line by line and you'll need much patience and an SSD disk :-) Clearly you can even simply read it line-by-line as a text file (in the end you want to simply rewrite it minus some lines)

Comment: See this post ► [**Reading large text files with streams in C#**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161895/reading-large-text-files-with-streams-in-c-sharp) One of the answers further down shows what they used to process a 19GB file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider migrating the CSV file to a SQL database, import it then remove the offending column. CSV is not really an efficient solution

Comment: Note you can always export back to CSV when you're done if you insist on using flat files

Comment: If you want to really go hard and keep using CSV, there's a Python module for that: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html