# Finding the property of an object in a large (20 GB) text file

Tags: c#

I have a large 20 GB text file with entries resembling `entry1MainText:entry1Name`, line separated.

I need to see if a property of an object matches `entry1MainText` in any of these lines. So far I have the below code (ref [Reading large text files with streams in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161895/reading-large-text-files-with-streams-in-c-sharp)) that reads a line of the file and performs a foreach for said object property. I realise this is likely not the most efficient way.

```
string file = @"C:\test.txt";

using (FileStream fs = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        foreach (UsrFile usrF in rawUsrSorted)
        {
            if (line.Contains(usrF.Prop1))
            {
                gridMain.Rows.Add(usrF.Prop1, usrF.Prop2);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I do have the benefit of having enough RAM to read the file into memory and parsing there if this would be of benefit, i.e. I have looked a little into `MemoryMappedFile` and wonder if this might be of use here.

Comment: I would think to some kind of indexing first, but that depends on how the data are written on the file (also assuming the file is static).

Comment: Did you try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/25936140/5555803?

Comment: @MarioVernari yes the file is static, nice idea.

Comment: There's an overload of `FileStream` that accepts a buffer size - using `BufferedStream` instead of that will actually make it slower,

Comment: What is `gridMain` by the way? If it's a `DataGridView` it is likely updating itself whenever you add a row to it. It would be much more efficient to use `.AddRange()` to update it in a oner.

Comment: I see you're using `Contains` to check if the line matches - but from the description it seems like you want to check `StartsWith(usrF.Prop1 + ":")`. Do you actually need to check if the text _contains_ the property, or do you want to check if they are equal?

Comment: If the file is static then do a transformation to a data format or storage format/type where searching is quicker. Any optimizations you do to the above code will be minimal compared to a better method for doing it.

Comment: @MatthewWatson good guess, yes it is. I'll look into this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. instantiate a new `FileStream` to get access to the buffer and flags
2. Adjust the buffer size, for SSD this can be quite large, I have chosen `1024 * 1000` (see what works for your drive)
3. Set the [`FileOptions.SequentialScan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileoptions?view=net-5.0) flag

> Indicates that the file is to be accessed sequentially from beginning
> to end. The system can use this as a hint to optimize file caching. If
> an application moves the file pointer for random access, optimum
> caching may not occur; however, correct operation is still guaranteed.
> Specifying this flag can increase performance in some cases.

4. Split the line
5. Use a `Dictionary`

**Example**

```
var dict = rawUsrSorted
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Prop1, x => x.Prop2);

using var fs = new FileStream(
    file, 
    FileMode.Open, 
    FileAccess.Read, 
    FileShare.ReadWrite, 
    1024 * 1000, 
    FileOptions.SequentialScan);

using var sr = new StreamReader(fs);

string line;
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   var prop = line[..line.IndexOf(":")];
   if (dict.TryGetValue(prop, out var prop2))
      gridMain.Rows.Add(prop, prop2); 
}
```

<sub>***Note** : This is completely untested, may contain any number of typos syntax errors or mistakes and lacks suitable error checking and fault tollerance*</sub>

<sub>***Also note** : You should really use a database, scanning a 20 gig file is extremely inefficient compared to an indexed table.*</sub>