# Split a monster json file in smaller json files

Tags: json

as by title I have a beast of json files that I would like to split into smaller files. The size of this json file is 8.7 Gb. The format/json are located at this link: [Detailed book graph](https://sites.google.com/eng.ucsd.edu/ucsdbookgraph/books?authuser=0)
. is the first paragraph. The file is big enough to saturate the RAM of my PC (32 GB)
I tried to look for some tools online or on github, but nothing worked. Anyone have any idea how I can do that?

Comment: i havent looked at the exact json file contents, but often for big data, the file contains a json-record per line. This means that the complete file isnt strictly parseable as json, but the individual lines are (the file is not a big array of json objects). So if that is the case, you can try a file readstream in whichever programming language you like.

Comment: In my opinion, you shoud write a program for reading that file. I think you need to read line by line or with fixed buffer size. Also you can check out this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161895/reading-large-text-files-with-streams-in-c-sharp

Comment: Using pandas or csv I wrote a program that reads line by line the json file. Unfortunately after 5 minutes the compiler returns the error  "Could not reserve memory block, "

Comment: The problem is that when I use functions like load json , python tries to load all the file information into RAM and then process it. At least I think he does that.