# Console.WriteLine slow

Tags: c#, performance

I run through millions of records and sometimes I have to debug using `Console.WriteLine` to see what is going on.

However, `Console.WriteLine` is very slow, considerably slower than writing to a file.

BUT it is very convenient - does anyone know of a way to speed it up?

Comment: System io is inheritantly slow

Comment: i don't think there is any way to speed it up more then to write less to it...

Comment: I agree with Petoj. Whenever I output e.g. real-time data, I put a counter / timer in to only output 1% or so.

Comment: I write to it the minimum amount, but for some test - it is still a huge amount.  I don't understand why should be slower than writing to file...

Comment: It is the updating the display that is expensive resource wise. Each line you write causes a redraw of the console window (if it is in view).

Comment: why not output to a log file instead then? and maybe only output to the console when it's an error?

Comment: @ManInMoon: Refreshing a window, and even if it is just the Console, can be very expensive, because there's a lot involved if it comes to redraw the UI.

Comment: You can use a buffer, and print the buffer from time to time.

Comment: Even if I close Output window - it's just as slow

Comment: @ManInMoon there are logging libraries with asynch features, so it doesn't wait for console to finish

Comment: @jb. perhaps because if one would immediately see where is a problem, they would fix it instead of printing? :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `OutputDebugString` API function to send a string to the debugger. It doesn't wait for anything to redraw and this is probably the fastest thing you can get without digging into the low-level stuff too much.
The text you give to this function will go into Visual Studio Output window.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern void OutputDebugString(string lpOutputString);
```

Then you just call `OutputDebugString("Hello world!");`

Comment: And even though the Ouput screen needs to redraw - you belive this is faster than Console.WriteLine which writes to the same place?

Comment: The Pretender - just tested this - BUT it hasn't written to Output window - could it be somewhere else?

Comment: As far as I understand, your problem is that Console.WriteLine takes too much time to execute and blocks your program flow until it's finished. `OutputDebugString` will return immediately, whether the Output window has redrawn itself or not.

If you are concerned with time between the function call and the time when you actually see the message, that's another story.

Comment: But where does OutputDebugString output to?

Comment: It seems that there's a problem with this method when it's used under .NET. When this function is called from native C++ application, its output goes straight into VS Output window, but when the same function is called from a managed program, the message gets lost somewhere. Sorry for misleading you, I'll try to look into this.

Comment: You can also use DebugView (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) то view these messages. I've just tested it with a sample .NET 4 console app and it works like a charm.

Comment: Yes - Itried that - but no messages. Do you have to flag soemthing in .NET - Debugmode???

Comment: OK, this is just weird. I've tried the exact same code at home, and DebugView ends up empty. But then I checked the “Enable unmanaged debugging” at “Debug” tab in my project preferences and `OutputDebugString` started to write to the VS Output window oO 
I suspect this is somehow related to the fact that I had multiple instances of VS opened at work. So if you enable that checkbox in project properties and run a single VS instance you should probably see your messages in the Output window.

Comment: Why not just use Debug.WriteLine()? However, it's also interesting for me, how refreshing a console window can be slower than redrawing a UI window (VS's Output). Or I've misunderstood smthg?Sorry for misleading

Answer (score 15):

If it is just for debugging purposes you should use [`Debug.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx) instead. This will most likely be a bit faster than using `Console.WriteLine`.

**Example**

```
Debug.WriteLine("There was an error processing the data.");
```

Comment: Where does that write to? i.e. how do I see it?

Comment: @MainInMoon, your `Output Window`.

Comment: Why would screen redrawing of that take less long than Console.WriteLIne?

Comment: Filip is right that Debug.WriteLine is faster.  But it's not just "a bit faster"... it's A LOT faster.

Comment: This is not faster than Console.WriteLine for me

Comment: The problem is that `Debug.WriteLine` is crippled. It's just wouldn't work unless a PC have an IDE.

Answer (score 10):

Do something like this:

```
public static class QueuedConsole
{
    private static StringBuilder _sb = new StringBuilder();
    private static int _lineCount;

    public void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        _sb.AppendLine(message);
        ++_lineCount;
        if (_lineCount >= 10)
           WriteAll();
    }

    public void WriteAll()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_sb.ToString());
        _lineCount = 0;
        _sb.Clear();
    }
}

QueuedConsole.WriteLine("This message will not be written directly, but with nine other entries to increase performance.");

//after your operations, end with write all to get the last lines.
QueuedConsole.WriteAll();
```

Here is another example: [Does Console.WriteLine block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670057/does-console-writeline-block)

Comment: Thanks for that. I have a fast writer that uses a file. I am just wondering why such a useful facility is slow - and forces us to come up with creative solutions...

Comment: Check the other answer that I added as a link.

Comment: Might be better to create a class then the destructor can print the remaining buffer if the prog. crashes.

Comment: Are you sure that the console is still intact if an application crashes?

Comment: I was thinking of exceptions that may be caught at a higher level rather than anything catastrophic.

Comment: jgauffin, you've looked at this quite deeply. Do you know why having the output closed whilst running DOES NOT speed things up?

Answer (score 10):

I recently did a benchmark battery for this on **.NET 4.8**. The tests included many of the proposals mentioned on this page, including `Async` and blocking variants of both BCL and custom code, and then most of those both with and without dedicated threading, and finally scaled across power-of-2 buffer sizes.

The fastest method, now used in my own projects, buffers 64K of wide ([Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)) characters at a time from **.NET** directly to the **Win32** function [`WriteConsoleW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole) without copying or even hard-pinning. Remainders larger than 64K, after filling and flushing one buffer, are also sent directly, and *in-situ* as well. The approach deliberately bypasses the `Stream`/`TextWriter` paradigm so it can (obviously enough) provide .NET text *that is already Unicode* to a (native) Unicode API without all the superfluous memory copying/shuffling and `byte[]` array allocations required for first "decoding" to a byte stream.

If there is interest (perhaps because the buffering logic is slightly intricate), I can provide the source for the above; it's only about 80 lines. However, my tests determined that there's a simpler way to get *nearly* the same performance, and since it doesn't require any Win32 calls, I'll show this latter technique instead.

The following is ***way faster*** than `Console.Write`:

```
public static class FastConsole
{
    static readonly BufferedStream str;

    static FastConsole()
    {
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;  // crucial

        // avoid special "ShadowBuffer" for hard-coded size 0x14000 in 'BufferedStream' 
        str = new BufferedStream(Console.OpenStandardOutput(), 0x15000);
    }

    public static void WriteLine(String s) => Write(s + "\r\n");

    public static void Write(String s)
    {
        // avoid endless 'GetByteCount' dithering in 'Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s)'
        var rgb = new byte[s.Length << 1];
        Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s, 0, s.Length, rgb, 0);

        lock (str)   // (optional, can omit if appropriate)
            str.Write(rgb, 0, rgb.Length);
    }

    public static void Flush() { lock (str) str.Flush(); }
};
```

Note that this is a buffered writer, so you must call `Flush()` when you have no more text to write.

I should also mention that, as shown, technically this code assumes 16-bit Unicode ([UCS-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Coded_Character_Set), as opposed to [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)) and thus won't properly handle 4-byte escape surrogates for characters beyond the [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane). The point hardly seems important given the more extreme limitations on console text display in general, but could perhaps still matter for piping/redirection.

**Usage:**

```
FastConsole.WriteLine("hello world.");
// etc...
FastConsole.Flush();
```

On my machine, this gets about **77,000 lines/second** (mixed-length) versus only **5,200** lines/sec under identical conditions for normal `Console.WriteLine`. That's a factor of almost 15x speedup.

These are controlled comparison results only; note that absolute measurements of console output performance are highly variable, depending on the console window settings and runtime conditions, including size, layout, fonts, DWM clipping, etc.

Comment: I tried calling `FastConsole.Flush` after each `FastConsole.WriteLine`, and the performance became almost identical with the native `Console.WriteLine`. I guess this was expected. The performance boost comes basically from omitting flushing the stream after each write.

Answer (score 6):

**Why Console is slow:**

- Console output is actually an IO stream that's managed by your operating system. Most IO classes (like `FileStream`) have async methods but the `Console` class was never updated so it always blocks the thread when writing.
- `Console.WriteLine` is backed by `SyncTextWriter` which uses a global lock to prevent multiple threads from writing partial lines. This is a major bottleneck that forces all threads to wait for each other to finish the write.
- If the console window is visible on screen then there can be significant slowdown because the window needs to be redrawn before the console output is considered flushed.

**Solutions:**

Wrap the Console stream with a `StreamWriter` and then use async methods:

```cs
var sw = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
await sw.WriteLineAsync("...");
```

You can also set a larger buffer if you need to use sync methods. The call will occasionally block when the buffer gets full and is flushed to the stream.

```cs
// set a buffer size
var sw = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput(), Encoding.UTF8, 8192);
// this write call will block when buffer is full
sw.Write("...")
```

If you want the fastest writes though, you'll need to make your own buffer class that writes to memory and flushes to the console asynchronously in the background using a single thread without locking. The [new `Channel<T>` class in .NET Core 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.1) makes this simple and fast. Plenty of other questions showing that code but comment if you need tips.

Comment: Am I right thinking that it's anyway gonna block a thread, right? Isn't this same as wrap a sync operation into something like `Task.Run` ? I see that `OpenStandardOutput` returns a `Stream` which provides an async API so that seems like I'm wrong and this is indeed asynchronous.

Comment: @E.Shcherbo No. The first option uses standard async methods for writing to a stream, and stdout is just a stream. All you have to do is initialize your own `StreamWriter` instead of using the static `Console` class. This still uses a global lock if you're writing the entire line so there will be contention, which is what I talk about near the end.

Answer (score 4):

A little old thread and maybe not exactly what the OP is looking for, but I ran into the same question recently, when processing audio data in real time.

I compared `Console.WriteLine` to `Debug.WriteLine` with [this code](https://pastebin.com/JRUviSUK) and used [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview)  as a dos box alternative. It's only an executable (nothing to install) and can be customized in very neat ways (filters & colors!). It has no problems with tens of thousands of lines and manages the memory quite well (I could not find any kind of leak, even after days of logging).

After doing some testing in different environments (e.g.: virtual machine, IDE, background processes running, etc) I made the following observations:

- `Debug` is almost always faster
- For small bursts of lines (<1000), it's about 10 times faster
- For larger chunks it seems to converge to about 3x
- If the `Debug` output goes to the IDE, `Console` is faster :-)
- If DebugView is not running, `Debug` gets even faster
- For really large amounts of consecutive outputs (>10000), `Debug` gets slower and `Console` stays constant. I presume this is due to the memory, Debug has to allocate and `Console` does not.
- Obviously, it makes a difference if DebugView is actually "in-view" or not, as the many gui updates have a significant impact on the overall performance of the system, while Console simply hangs, if visible or not. But it's hard to put numbers on that one...

I did not try multiple threads writing to the `Console`, as I think this should generally avoided. I never had (performance) problems when writing to `Debug` from multiple threads.

If you compile with Release settings, usually all `Debug` statements are omitted and `Trace` should produce the same behaviour as Debug.

I used **VS2017** & **.Net 4.6.1**

Sorry for so much code, but I had to tweak it quite a lot to actually measure what I wanted to. If you can spot any problems with the code (biases, etc.), please comment. I would love to get more precise data for real life systems.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace Console_vs_Debug {
 class Program {
  class Trial {
   public string name;
   public Action console;
   public Action debug;
   public List < float > consoleMeasuredTimes = new List < float > ();
   public List < float > debugMeasuredTimes = new List < float > ();
  }

  static Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
  private static int repeatLoop = 1000;
  private static int iterations = 2;
  private static int dummy = 0;

  static void Main(string[] args) {
   if (args.Length == 2) {
    repeatLoop = int.Parse(args[0]);
    iterations = int.Parse(args[1]);
   }

   // do some dummy work
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine("-");
    Debug.WriteLine("-");
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    foreach(Trial trial in trials) {
     Thread.Sleep(50);
     sw.Restart();
     for (int r = 0; r < repeatLoop; r++)
      trial.console();
     sw.Stop();
     trial.consoleMeasuredTimes.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
     Thread.Sleep(1);
     sw.Restart();
     for (int r = 0; r < repeatLoop; r++)
      trial.debug();
     sw.Stop();
     trial.debugMeasuredTimes.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    }
   }
   Console.WriteLine("---\r\n");
   foreach(Trial trial in trials) {
    var consoleAverage = trial.consoleMeasuredTimes.Average();
    var debugAverage = trial.debugMeasuredTimes.Average();
    Console.WriteLine(trial.name);
    Console.WriteLine($ "    console: {consoleAverage,11:F4}");
    Console.WriteLine($ "      debug: {debugAverage,11:F4}");
    Console.WriteLine($ "{consoleAverage / debugAverage,32:F2} (console/debug)");
    Console.WriteLine();
   }

   Console.WriteLine("all measurements are in milliseconds");
   Console.WriteLine("anykey");
   Console.ReadKey();
  }

  private static List < Trial > trials = new List < Trial > {
   new Trial {
    name = "constant",
     console = delegate {
      Console.WriteLine("A static and constant string");
     },
     debug = delegate {
      Debug.WriteLine("A static and constant string");
     }
   },
   new Trial {
    name = "dynamic",
     console = delegate {
      Console.WriteLine("A dynamically built string (number " + dummy++ + ")");
     },
     debug = delegate {
      Debug.WriteLine("A dynamically built string (number " + dummy++ + ")");
     }
   },
   new Trial {
    name = "interpolated",
     console = delegate {
      Console.WriteLine($ "An interpolated string (number {dummy++,6})");
     },
     debug = delegate {
      Debug.WriteLine($ "An interpolated string (number {dummy++,6})");
     }
   }
  };
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the System.Diagnostics Debug class? You can accomplish the same things as using Console.WriteLine.

[You can view the available class methods here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug).

Comment: If you meant `Debug.WriteLine`, it isn't. It seems to be a common misconception. That just wouldn't work unless a PC have an IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little trick I use sometimes: If you remove focus from the Console window by opening another window over it, and leave it until it completes, it won't redraw the window until you refocus, speeding it up significantly. Just make sure you have the buffer set up high enough that you can scroll back through all of the output.

Comment: I haven;t found that that helps... even if I close Output winodw - the speed is the same

Comment: I don't think this makes a difference, either.