# Speed up the Console Application

Tags: c#, multithreading, console-application

I developed a console application which takes the ipaddress as input and provides the uptime of the devices in the log file. Totally 27000 ipaddress are there. it takes nearly 2 days to give the output.

Please help how can i make speed my application using multi therading.

Comment: You will not be able to read all those lines anyway so I would suggest saving to file. Console output is pretty slow

Comment: Also, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272177/console-writeline-slow

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class Program
{
    internal static string Result(string ip)
    {
       // your function here
    }

    internal static void Main()
    {
        const int ParallelJobs = 100;

        var ips = File.ReadAllLines("your.data");

        var results = ips.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(ParallelJobs ).Select(Result).ToList();

        File.WriteAllLines("your.results", results);
    }
}
```

Basically, that's it. Now it runs in parallel. Your jobs seem to be I/O bound with a lot of idle waiting time, so I would set the degree of parallelism quite high. "Waiting" can be done in huge batches :)

Comment: For network I/O you'll want to add a MaxDegereeOfParalle option.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes, indeed. But you cannot with PLinq, that's why I specifically mentioned the other methods, where you can.

Comment: `AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(8).Select(...)`

Comment: @HenkHolterman woaw, never saw that. Looked for a parameter but never found it. That's damn cool. Thanks a lot!