# Why is the built in Console Logger making my Netcore Web API slow?

Tags: .net-core

I'm running a Netcore Web API through visual studio and after 40-60 requests it becomes unresponsive. Requests that would typically take under a second start taking over a minute.

I disabled the console logger and the API never slows down no matter how many requests I send to it.

Here is how I add the console logger:

```
loggerFactory.AddConsole( Configuration.GetSection( "Logging" ) );
```

Comment: We use NLog from web applications and web apis, and never seen any significant performance difference. It all depends on the config of NLog. Also it could depend on the indexes in your db.

Comment: Have you tried to use `<targets async="true">` ? Maybe share your nlog.config, or do some profiling.

Comment: @Julian Just discovered that it isn't NLog but the console logger that is causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately writing (multi threaded) to console is slow. It's not an limitation of NLog self.

See also [Console.WriteLine slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5272177/201303)